# "the town ( where/ which ) I was born" vs. "the town ( where/ which ) I was born in"

Tags: prepositions, where-which

This is the town ........( where/ which) I was born.
This is the town ........( where/ which) I was born in.

Which word in parenthesis is correct? As we can see, the second one has " in " at the end, and I want to know if it makes any difference.

Comment: The town where I was born, or the town in which I was born.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 answers:

1. This is the town where I was born.
2. This is the town in which I was born.

I see that you have pointed out the *in* at the end of the second sentence. However it does not gel very well with either of the two - *where/ which* - in that position.

The sentence would be:
*This is the town which I was born in* and it sounds rather odd.

*In* must go with *which*, but as shown in the usage 2 above.

Let me point you to a similar discussion [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/131289/how-to-say-where-i-was-born/131293).

Hope this helps.

NS